# Wordpress plugin: reverse proxy a static file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin. How can I make the plugin reverse proxy a javascript file? For example, the HTML file will load a script tag: `<script src="/script.js"></script>`. `/script.js` does not exist in the web server's file system, I want to fetch it from `https://othersite.com/script.js` and return it to the client.

For reasons:

- I cannot modify webserver config by hand (.htaccess or nginx.conf). However, programmatically modifying config with PHP is fine.
- I cannot perform an HTTP redirection (30x).

Here's what I have so far:

```php
<?php

function reverse_proxy_file() {
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] === '/script.js') {
        $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://othersite.com/script.js' );
        foreach($response['headers'] as $i => $item) {
            header("{$i}: {$item}");
        }
        http_response_code($response['response']['code']);
        echo $response['body'];
        die;
    }
}

add_action('init', 'reverse_proxy_file');

?>
```

The problem is the request for `/script.js` never appears in hooks, the if statement body isn't reached. The request receives a 404 response.

EDIT: I installed wordpress with https://localbyflywheel.com/, which uses nginx by default. I think nginx swallowed the static asset request, because the request never made it to PHP. For example, a request to `/script.js` resulted in an nginx 404 page whereas a request to `/script` resulted in a wordpress 404 page.

Because my plugin cannot enforce the usage of Apache, I decided to change the script src to `/script`, so that the request bypasses the webserver and reaches PHP, then I can serve whatever content I want.

Comment: Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/115896/16227 There are examples that include `wp_remote_retrieve_body`.

Comment: If you can’t handle this via URL rewriting, then you will either need to “capture” and rewrite `<script src="/script.js"></script>` before it reaches the client - or you let the 404 mechanism handle this. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/194384 shows how you can hook into that. Check if the request was for `/script.js` at that point, and if so, return your fetched script content (add appropriate headers, as far as necessary, and then exit.)

Comment: On my installation (Apache 2.4.18 with the unmodified .htaccess - i.e, has the line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f) I think your code would work. I suggest  provide more context about your server environment.

Comment: @MagentaCuda thanks, i edited my question. the problem was local flywheel & nginx